# SAS linear regression error

Tags: sas, linear-regression

I am a beginner level programmer in SAS and I am running into some issues trying to do LR.

I am trying to run a multivariate linear regression on a dataset (ads.csv, predicting sales based on the TV, radio, and newspapers figures)

```
S_no,TV,Radio,Newspaper,Sales

1,230.1,37.8,69.2,22.1

2,44.5,39.3,45.1,10.4

3,17.2,45.9,69.3,9.3

4,151.5,41.3,58.5,18.5
```

However when I run the linear regression in SAS using the initial coded to declare the output data, I get an error that saying :  ERROR: Output SAS data set must be provided.

```
options linesize=180 pagesize=180 nodate pageno=1;
libname Linreg1 "/folders/myfolders";
proc import datafile="/folders/myfolders/ads.csv";
out=Linreg1.output dbms=dlm replace;
delimiter=,;
getnames=yes;
run;
```

Following is the complete log of this small piece of code :

```
1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 55         
 56         options linesize=180 pagesize=180 nodate pageno=1;
 57         libname Linreg1 "/folders/myfolders";
 NOTE: Libref LINREG1 was successfully assigned as follows: 
   Engine:        V9 
   Physical Name: /folders/myfolders
 58         proc import datafile="/folders/myfolders/ads.csv";
 ERROR: Output SAS data set must be provided.
 NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Premature semi-colon. Remove the semi-colon after the datafile statement.

Comment: Marked as close under simple typographical error.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit: as Reeza said in that first comment] There are extra semicolons in there - your proc import line needs to read as below:

```
options linesize=180 pagesize=180 nodate pageno=1;
libname Linreg1 "/folders/myfolders";
proc import datafile="/folders/myfolders/ads.csv" out=Linreg1.output dbms=dlm replace;
delimiter=,;
getnames=yes;
run;
```

Comment: Isn't this just replicating the content of the first comment?

Comment: ha! Oh man, my bad - 100% it is. I didn't see an answer there.